# QGIS Concave Hull maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, clustering, concave-hull

I get this error when I run the Concave Hull (k-nearest neighbor) tool.

I have a point layer clustered with dbscan algorithm and I would like to draw a polygon around each cluster. I removed duplicated points before the processing and eventually have 7965 points with 56 clusters

QGIS error:

`return math.atan2(to_point[1] - from_point[1], to_point[0] - from_point[0]) RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

[image: qgis concave hull error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with the following solution:

The concave hull algorithm does not work for clusters with less than 3 points. Therefore, I modified the code to only run the algorithm for clusters that have more than 2 points.